# Show that $\mathbf{E}[\hat{X}\mid Y]=\mathbf{E} \left[ \mathbf{E} \left[ X\mid Y \right] \mid Y \right ]=\hat{X}$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $$\hat{X}=\mathbf{E}[X\mid Y]$$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. Then $\hat{X}$ is a random variable too.

My question is how to show that $$\mathbf{E}[\hat{X}\mid Y]=\hat{X}$$

I tried: $$\mathbf{E}[\hat{X}\mid Y]=\mathbf{E} \left[ \mathbf{E} \left[ X\mid Y \right] \mid Y \right ]$$ Unfortunately I don't know what to do with this. I know the definition of conditional random variables but I do not have a joint PDF of $(\hat{X} \mid Y) $.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: Check that $\mathbf E[\hat X\,|\,Y]$ has all the properties required of $\mathbf E[X\,|\,Y]$, and must therefore equal (a.s.) $\mathbf E[X\,|\,Y]$ by the uniqueness of the latter object.

Comment: now it is clear.